# Match fulltext exclude html , urls

Tags: php, regex, full-text-search

I want to match in a html code all Text.
But only text with all punctuation characters, but without html like  or urls etc.

example:

```
<div class="description">Boys loving girls</div>
```

match result:

```
Boys loving girls
```

---

example:

```
<div class="description">
guys loving girls! 
</div><br />
```

match result:

```
guys loving girls!
```

my try:

```
(?!.*(?:http:\/\/))^[a-z0-9():+,\-.@;\$_\!*\'%\?\säüöß%]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) to learn more about parsing HTML content.

You should not use regex for this kind of task.

---

If you want to use regex anyway, then try the following regex pattern:

```
$pattern = '/^(?!.*(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:[^>]*>|)\s*([^<]+)(?:<.*|)\s*$/';
```

Comment: isnt threre a simple regex solution possible? like exclude: <.*> or so?

Comment: sry want work because there could be also simple text without html like see edited example at first post

Comment: looks good. but the url exclude is mising ive tried this (?!.*(?:https?:\/\/))(?:>\s*(.*?)\s*<|^\s*([^><]*?)\s*$) but not all urls are excluded hmm

Comment: ok when i disable"match at line breaks ^$" then it not working with normal text without html tags <div> etc...

Comment: @Nicy - please see the updated answer and please clean up (remove) the comments above to make this post clear.